# How do I choose from an agent-set that depends on an attribute?

Tags: netlogo

I have a model where the male turtles get classified according to a threshold as follows:

```
    ifelse(condition > threshold)  [set status 0 ] [set status 1]
```

I want to count the potential male mates of each of the females in the population who meet this threshold. I've coded it so the females are limited to having a 10-patch radius of detection. If there are no males that meet this threshold then FR should be 0 otherwise it should be a proportion.

```
      ask turtles with [sex = "female"] [if any? turtles with [sex = "male"] 
      in-radius 10 [ set potentialMates turtles with [sex = "male"] in-radius 10]
        ifelse any?  potentialMates with [anadromousM = 1] 
        [set FR count potentialMates with [anadromousM = 1] / count potentialMates ]
        [set FR 0]]
```

When I run this I get the error for the second `any?`

> ANY? expected input to be an agentset but got the number 0 instead.

Where am I going wrong? Hope you can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easier to see with different indenting. The following is your code (wrapped in a procedure name).

```
to find-mate
  ask turtles with [sex = "female"]
  [ if any? turtles with [sex = "male"] in-radius 10
    [ set potentialMates turtles with [sex = "male"] in-radius 10
    ]
    ifelse any? potentialMates with [anadromousM = 1] 
    [ set FR count potentialMates with [anadromousM = 1] / count potentialMates ]
    [ set FR 0]
  ]
end
```

As you can see, the `ifelse` is tested (for each female turtle) regardless of the outcome of `if any? turtles with [sex = "male"] in-radius 10`. Imagine this first `if` is `false`, then the potentialMates `agentset` never gets created with the male turtles. Hence the error. You haven't shown us the code where pontentialMates is first instantiated - assuming it is a global variable, then it will have the value 0.

I think you want FR to be 0 in the case where there are no males in the radius at all. In that case, try this.

```
to find-mate
  ask turtles with [sex = "female"]
  [ ifelse any? turtles with [sex = "male"] in-radius 10
    [ set potentialMates turtles with [sex = "male"] in-radius 10
      set FR count potentialMates with [anadromousM = 1] / count potentialMates
    ]
    [ set FR 0]
  ]
end
```

If there's no potentialMates with anadromousM = 1 then the numerator is 0 anyway, and 0/N is 0.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. `potentialMates` is a `turtles-own` variable

Comment: In that case, it is created when the turtle is created and is given the value 0 (which is NetLogo's default variable value). I will update the answer.